# CiviMailings stuck on 'running'

Tags: civimail

We run CiviCRM 4.6.2 with Wordpress 4.2.3. I have run a couple of large Mailings recently and they get stuck 'running'.  I know some recipients have received them although the reports say 0% have been delivered.  I don't want to execute the cron job again as previously some recipients then received the mailing twice.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You might check the mailing list itself, as we have seen mailings get stuck due to an improperly formatted/invalid email address on the list.  Another idea might be to split your list in half and send the mailing in two groups, in case the mailing size is an issue with your server.

Good luck,
Lesley

Answer (score 2):

This is very late, but this answer might be useful for others.

We have seen this a couple of times. Usually it is caused by an error code due to some limits on the SMTP server as @Lesley Carter mentioned.

Unfortunutately CiviMail does not capture and display these anywhere as far as I can tell. So you have the get into the logs of your mailing software.

As to duplicate sendings you can actually make a group of those that have already received the mailing using "Report" and listing all successful deliveries. You can then use that group to "Not include" when you do your second round.